# Extend the x-axis line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

The x-axis for my [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri2Pn.jpg) seems to a bit shorter and I wanted it be longer than that. Tried using limits and breaks but that only works on the shorter x-axis. Could anyone tell me where i'm going wrong or what should I be doing to extend the x-axis? Thanks!

the code:

```
plot <- ggplot(df_noemp, aes(x = VA, y = VF, image = image_link)) +
  geom_image(aes(image = image_link), size = 0.05, by = "height", asp = 0.8) + 
  labs(
    x = paste0("<span style='font-size: 11pt'><b>abcd</b></span><br><span style='font-size: 7pt'>abc</span><br>"),
    y = paste0("<span style='font-size: 11pt'><b>abcd</b></span><br><span style='font-size: 7pt'>abc</span>"),
    title = paste0("<br><span style='font-size: 17pt'>abcd</span><br><span style='font-size: 9pt'>abc</span><br>")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"), limits = c(-250, 60))+
  #coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-150, 60))+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"), limits=c(-75, 60))+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "dashed", color = "#fafafa"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#2e2e2e", size = 8, family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#2e2e2e", size = 8, family = "Tw Cen MT", angle = 90),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 0, face = "bold", family = "Trebuchet MS"),
    plot.caption = element_markdown(margin = margin(t = 20), size = 6, family = "Trebuchet MS"),
    plot.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = "#f5f5f5"),
    axis.line.x = element_line(color="#2e2e2e", size = 0.6),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="#2e2e2e", size = 0.6),
    axis.title.x = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 0, family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown(angle = 90, family = "Tw Cen MT"),
    plot.margin = margin(0,0.4,-0.05,-3, "cm"),
    aspect.ratio = 1/0.8
  ) 
 
ggsave(
  "var-asp-theme.png", plot, 
  # make the width equivalent to the aspect.ratio
  height = 9, width = 8, dpi = "retina"
)
```

```
Dataframe:

 VF  VA  image_link
 10  30   path_one
-20   4   path_two
 50 -70   path_three and so on
```

**EDIT (Solution)**

```
After multiple trial and errors of aspect ratio, plot_margin and width/height, I found the combination that I'm happy with.
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *a bit shorter* and *I wanted it be longer than that*? If you want to increase the range of the x axis you could simply do so via `limits=`, e.g. `limits = c(-75, 75)`.

Comment: Not the range, but the actual length of the x-axis. The length of the line is a bit smaller and I wanted it to extend 

Hope I explained it better @stefan

Comment: Well, your x axis extends to the border of the panel. The issue is that you fixed the aspect ratio. Doing so the plot will not adjust to the size of the plotting device and will in general not fit. As a result you end up with some blank space on the left/right or bottom/top. To make that visible set `color="red"` for `plot.background`. To fix that set the width/height in ggsave so that the plot fits into the plotting device.

Comment: Thanks for this @stefan. After a lot of trial and error, found the aspect ratio, plot_margin and width/height that I'm happy with!